# Package TsDyn. SelectSETAR function

Tags: r

I want to apply the SelectSet  function to a list of variables. If I do this:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(emi)) {
   print(i)
   search <- selectSETAR(emi[,i], m=3, thDelay=2)
   set <- setar(emi[,i], m=3, thDelay=2, th=search$th)
   print(search)
   summary(set)
}
```

The summary  instruction is overlooked and in fact this is the more important output for me.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `print()` as you did for `i` and `search`. For example:

```
> for (i in 1:2) {
+    print(i)
+    summary(rnorm(10*i))
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

but

```
> for (i in 1:2) {
+    print(i)
+    print(summary(rnorm(10*i)))
+ }
[1] 1
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.65260 -0.32320 -0.02333  0.21530  0.82060  1.59900 
[1] 2
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-1.38000 -0.52860  0.04965  0.07786  0.59130  1.76200
```